# Send a transaciton to Sepolia network but it can't be found from `sepolia.etherscan.io`

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs

I am using below code to call a smart contract deployed in Sepolia network.

```
const w = new Web3('https://rpc.sepolia.org');
      await w.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
            {
              from: account.address,
              to: contractAddress,
              gas: 1000000,
              gasPrice: 1000000000,
              nonce: await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
              data: await contract.methods
                .createSector(
                  
                  { value: web3.utils.fromWei(price, 'ether') }
                )
                .encodeABI(),
            },
            privateKey
          );
```

the method returns successfully with below response:

```
messageHash:"0x1e1f185df0e3ee4f761d9daa134fcb8a27fabb70c8e29f7530dac4ba9c97d7b7"
r: "0x767fb11d7f7b797153b31cbcf5421097d786294f58624bdb3ba2d359a205c8be"
rawTransaction: "0xf8ed04843b9aca00830f42409438cf5792107ac6c52bc8ec87c6b61be1bc2593a480b884dbf9fdee000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018401546d72a0767fb11d7f7b797153b31cbcf5421097d786294f58624bdb3ba2d359a205c8bea06a96730d49eee59437230dbc246a01ce897e5ca8b2e148df4ffcab73b2020f7d"
s: "0x6a96730d49eee59437230dbc246a01ce897e5ca8b2e148df4ffcab73b2020f7d"
transactionHash: "0x2d61c390f0e90abb36494b3a76017bd6597420882ae993ab3d4c634c5ba9f455"
v: "0x1546d72"
```

but I can't find the transaciotn hash `0x2d61c390f0e90abb36494b3a76017bd6597420882ae993ab3d4c634c5ba9f455` from `sepolia.etherscan.io`.

Both contract address and account address can be found. I have waited for a few hours but the transaction is still not shown. Do I need to do something else to make it work?

The contract address: 0x38CF5792107Ac6c52bC8eC87c6b61BE1bC2593a4
The account address: 0x3DfBb8A11C003c2468fE69F4F6Cc80b5F14c433D

Comment: I faced the same issue several time, it's weird but I think it's ok. You don't do anything wrong, just retry.

Contract address can be found doesn't mean your transaction work, you must see the tx which create your contract and your bytecode inside that address to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `w.eth.accounts.signTransaction` you are only signing the transaction without broadcasting it.

To broadcast you can try:

```
const signedTx = await w.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
  {
    from: account.address,
    to: contractAddress,
    gas: 1000000,
    gasPrice: 1000000000,
    nonce: await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
    data: await contract.methods
      .createSector(
        
        { value: web3.utils.fromWei(price, 'ether') }
      )
      .encodeABI(),
  },
  privateKey
);

await w.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that the transaction verification was not performed successfully or there was insufficient gas.

Comment: is there any way to check the failed transaction? In terms of insufficient gas, wouldn't it return it from the sendTransaction call?